# Dynamically wrap index with array using while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

My code speaks for me, I want to wrap array index with another array dynamically (with a loop).

The following code does not work.  Please, help me to convert this "x" string to JavaScript code or to find the right way to get the result.

```
var x = parentTasks[j];

while(x){
    x = parentTasks + '[' + numbers + '[' + x + ']]';
}
```

Later "x" will become undefined, so then loop should stop.

**What I expect:**

Example when loop is iterated for 1st time:

```
parentTasks[numbers[parentTasks[j]]]
```

Example when loop is iterated for 2nd time:

```
parentTasks[numbers[parentTasks[numbers[parentTasks[j]]]]]
```

Comment: This is called telescoping, I believe

Comment: Maybe you can share some links or hints?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by my self. Here is a solution:

```
var x = parentTasks[j];
var z = 0
while ( z++ < 2 ) {

    x = 'parentTasks[numbers[' + x + ']]';

    console.log(eval(x));
}
```